# Redux-Form not running mapStateToProps function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

The redux-form docs say that the `reduxForm()` decorator accepts one required argument (the config object) and four optional arguments (the same four arguments that get passed to the `connect` decorator in react-redux). However, when I pass my `mapStateToProps()` function as an argument to the `reduxForm()` decorator, `mapStateToProps()` isn't actually getting run. See a simplified code example below. The interpreter never reaches the `debugger` statement. Am I misunderstanding something about the redux-form docs?

```
import React from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>This is the home component.</div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  debugger;
  const {
    ui: {
      isMailingListFormVisible
    }
  } = state;
  return {
    isMailingListFormVisible
  };
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'mailingList',
  fields: ['firstName', 'email']
}, mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

Comment: as of V6, reduxForm no longer accepts those arguments and you must use the 'connect' function from react-redux.

Answer (score 1):

Your code didn't work on v6 simply because on v6 you have to decorate your Form component and connect the whole to the store manually:

```
import ...

class MyForm extends React.Component { 
    ...
}

MyForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'myForm',
  ...
})(MyForm);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you're not misunderstanding the docs. I've run your code example and it hits the debugger statement just fine.

Answer (score 0):

And you're placing it somewhere inside a `<Provider>` component?

I honestly can't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Yup. It's definitely inside a `<Provider>`. Do you know what version of redux-form you're using? I've tried this on 5.0.0 and 6.0.0-alpha.4. It's not reaching the debugger statement with either.

Comment: Never mind. I tried this initially with 6.0.0-alpha.4, and it didn't work. Then, I tried clearing out the node_modules directory, and reinstalling v6.0.0-alpha.4. Still didn't work. Then, I switched to v5.0.0. Still didn't work. Then, I cleared out the node_modules directory and reinstalled v5.0.0, and it finally started working. Maybe there are some breaking API changes in v6?

Comment: This was my fault. I apologize.